# help with Installing Ubuntu virtually

Tags: vmware

As i was recently introduced to the Ubuntu, i tried somehow to engage and become a user of such widespread and brilliant OS.
So i found that the most convenient way of installing Ubuntu is through Virtual disk machine (VMWare) on my VIO VGN-TT27GD Notepad already running a windows VISTA from back in 2011. 
I found this method the most convenient way to approach Ubuntu since i deemed it wise not to change my original OS on my Notepad.
So i downloaded a Desktop-i386 Ubuntu 14.04.3 ISO file the L.T.S version on my desktop in accordance of my primary OS of 32-bit Windows.

However there is a problem i seem to be encountering at the end of the installation process of Ubuntu through VMWare and that is when the last bit comes up where it is going to boot up and it requests for my Ubuntu user and password. i type in my User and following it comes the password which i should type in, but nothing on my keyboard is enabled to type anything in front of the password section within a starting page like command. so i have been unable so far to pass the login bit of the installation in order to get through to the Ubuntu and i can't seem to be getting my head round it or think of any way to get through onto the OS. 
i have done it a few times and the result has been the same (my keyboard not working in front of the password). 
the message that i get confronted on that section is as below;

"PLEASE WAIT! VMWare tool is currently being installed on your system. depending on the version of Ubuntu you are installing, you may log in below and use the system during the installation. otherwise, please wait for your graphical environment to launch. thank you."
Ubuntu login; my user works
              my password (there i can't type anything.

so neither waiting, nor typing my login detail work.
the OS is almost installed but i can't get through to it.
i appreciate you taking ure time on this and in case of any suggestion, solutions or any alternatives please let me know.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the on-screen keyboard? You can enable it by clicking on the Universal Access indicator on the top-right of your screen and then click on Virtual Keyboard.

Comment: no i can't get access to the Ubuntu desktop to enable its Virtual keyboard.  i'm still on virtual disk. tnx by the way.